# Google Drive uploads file OK but cannot view it

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, jspdf

The code below is working at loading a PDF file (created with jsPDF) into my Google Drive folder. It is essentially Google Drive the Quickstart code modified.

The PDF generated looks OK when viewed inside the browser that is opened with "docMenu.output('dataurlnewwindow');"

The PDF file appears OK in my Google Drive folder, but when I go to view it I get a grey screen with "Failed to load PDF document". I have no execution errors in console / inspect.

What have I missed? Have I messed up by pulling the Blob (data URI) and feeding it to Google Drive upload?

Many thanks!

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      var CLIENT_ID = 'my-client-id';
      var SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive';
      var FOLDER_ID = 'my-folder-id';

      /**
       * Called when the client library is loaded to start the auth flow.
       */
      function handleClientLoad() {
        window.setTimeout(checkAuth, 1);
      }

      /**
       * Check if the current user has authorized the application.
       */
      function checkAuth() {
        gapi.auth.authorize(
            {'client_id': CLIENT_ID, 'scope': SCOPES, 'immediate': true},
            handleAuthResult);
      }

      /**
       * Called when authorization server replies.
       * @param {Object} authResult Authorization result.
       */
      function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
        if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
          // Access token has been successfully retrieved, requests can be sent to the API.

           var docMenu = new jsPDF('p', 'cm', 'a5');   <-- Create PDF document
           docMenu.text(2, 1, "Testing");           <-- Add text here...
           docMenu.text(2, 5, "Testing");
           docMenu.text(2, 10, "Testing");
           docMenu.text(2, 15, "Testing");
           docMenu.text(2, 20, "Please order and pay at the counter.");
           docMenu.output('dataurlnewwindow');    <-- Displays PDF perfectly

           var MyBlob = docMenu.output('blob');     <-- get PDF Blob
           MyBlob.name = "test.pdf";                <-- Give it a file name

           insertFile(MyBlob);         <-- send it to Google Drive upload routine

        } else {
        alert("FAILED AUTHORIZING");        
        }
      }

      /**
       * Start the file upload.
       * @param {Object} evt Arguments from the file selector.
       */
      function uploadFile(evt) {
        gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', function() {
          var file = evt.target.files[0];
          insertFile(file);
        });
      }

      /**
       * Insert new file.
       * @param {File} fileData File object to read data from.
       * @param {Function} callback Function to call when the request is complete.
       */
      function insertFile(fileData, callback) {
        const boundary = '-------314159265358979323846';
        const delimiter = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n";
        const close_delim = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--";

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsBinaryString(fileData);
        reader.onload = function(e) {
          var contentType = fileData.type || 'application/octet-stream';
          var metadata = {
            'title': fileData.name,
            'mimeType': contentType,
            'parents': [{"id":FOLDER_ID}]
          };

          var base64Data = btoa(reader.result);
          var multipartRequestBody =
              delimiter +
              'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n' +
              JSON.stringify(metadata) +
              delimiter +
              'Content-Type: ' + contentType + '\r\n' +
              'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n' +
              '\r\n' +
              base64Data +
              close_delim;

          var request = gapi.client.request({
              'path': '/upload/drive/v2/files/',
              'method': 'POST',
              'params': {'uploadType': 'multipart'},
              'headers': {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary="' + boundary + '"'
              },
              'body': multipartRequestBody});
          if (!callback) {
            callback = function(file) {
              console.log(file)
            };
          }
          request.execute(callback);
        }
      }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who it may help, the above code works perfectly for me in creating and uploading PDF files to Google Drive using jsPDF.

The issue I was facing was one of Drive not liking this PDF for some reason (as it is reported with other PDFs in forums).

The file downloads OK and opens perfectly in Acrobat, Foxit and others... the problem is with Google.

Answer (score 0):

Do you think you need to change the file's permissions in Google Drive when it is created so that "anyone with a link" can view it or make it public?

Could it be the file is corrupt and Google Drive can't read it, but the docMenu.output method somehow isn't affected by the corruption? I have had something similar happen before.

I don't really have any experience with creating PDFs, but I hope my suggestion may at least point you in the right direction if it's correct.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the suggestion. The file is not corrupt when the output method displays it on the screen. It is only corrupt when opening it from Google Drive. Re permissions on the file, I seem to be able to open it, download it and delete it, so reading it should be OK. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe it is not corrupt, but what if it's just in a format Google Drive can't read.

Comment: Yes, it could be, but this is where I am stuck. I get the blob from jsPDF for this file then send it to Google upload which basically determines the file type then it uploads. It does this with no error so this is where I am stuck.

Comment: I think it may have to do with different endian types, check these out and see if it helps:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12556892/how-to-retrieve-a-byte-array-from-the-blobstore
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pydata/ksIPthf2NJI

Comment: Hi, solved. Google Drive is not so nice to PDFs at times. The file works well once downloaded and opened in a reader.